# having trouble with luxon, calculating time difference between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, luxon

kind people of StackOverflow, I'm having a problem with luxon (I guess I set it up wrong or did something wrong with it), right now it can't calculate future dates (says NaN), and for past dates take years into account so you get something like this:

[image]

[image]

[[image]

[image]

what I want this code to do is focus on month and day (forget about the year) and if the passed date is 7 days away or is less than 7 days away from today's date say "the passed date is <= a week", later this will trigger a notifier, that will notify me a week in advance of my friends & families bdays.

the code:

```
const isBirthdayThisWeek = (birthDate) => {
  const endDate = DateTime.now()
  const startDate = DateTime.fromISO(birthDate)
  const interval = Interval.fromDateTimes(startDate, endDate)
  const dateDifference = interval.length('days')
  const wholeNumberedDateDifference = Math.round(dateDifference)
  wholeNumberedDateDifference <= 7
    ? console.log('bday is in less than a week', wholeNumberedDateDifference)
    : wholeNumberedDateDifference > 7
      ? console.log('bday is more than in a week', wholeNumberedDateDifference)
      : console.log('something went wrong', wholeNumberedDateDifference)
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-bouman-1ugm3?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) and for the given date `"2021-04-16"` to now is, ~7.9 days, which is greater than 7. I see the correct output.

Comment: Oh, I see, if you select same start and end date the interval length is `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the magnitude of a compute duration. Durations work for both intervals into the future and past. Adjust the start date to "snap" to the same current year so the date diff doesn't cross year boundary.

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const startDate = DateTime.fromISO("2000-04-26").set({
  year: DateTime.now().get("year")
});
const diff = Math.abs(startDate.diffNow().as('day'));
const wholeNumberedDateDifference = Math.round(diff);
if (diff <= 7) {
  console.log("bday is in less than a week", wholeNumberedDateDifference);
} else {
  console.log("bday is more than in a week", wholeNumberedDateDifference);
}
```

## Output

```
bday is in less than a week 2
```

## Demo

[image: Edit having-trouble-with-luxon-calculating-time-difference-between-2-dates]

Comment: thanks, it now works for future dates, but still, doesn't work for passed dates                   const startDate = DateTime.fromISO('2020-04-26')                                                       
bday is more than in a week 363                                                                                     sorry Idk maybe I'm using the wrong plugin or I formulated the question wrong?                    what I want to do is calculate month and day don't take into account year so if my friend was born in 1988 it would still print to console 2 days instead of 12051 days.

Comment: const startDate = DateTime.fromISO("2000-04-26");
const diff = Math.abs(startDate.diffNow().as("day"));
const wholeNumberedDateDifference = Math.round(diff);
if (diff <= 7) {
  console.log("bday is in less than a week", wholeNumberedDateDifference);
} else {
  console.log("bday is more than in a week", wholeNumberedDateDifference);
}
logs to the console "bday is more than in a week 7668 days "

Comment: @eliasbnk I don't see what the hold up is... it computes the diff to a date from now, gets the number of days, and the number of days can either be less than or equal to 7 days (a week), or greater than. What are you expecting to work differently?

Comment: @David Reese sorry, I'm not great at formulating my thoughts. I think because of that we have somewhat of a misunderstanding. if you pass to DateTime.fromISO(); the birthday 1988-04-26 it will prints out 12051 days, that's the correct difference between the days, and your function works great to compute that.  but I don't know how I can tell the function to only compute the difference between months and days ( treat it as if it is the same year) so if I passed 1988-04-26 or 2020-04-26 or 1999-04-26 it would print out 2 days regardless of the year. thank you for being so patient and kind to me.

Comment: you're the best thank you so much. wish you the best.